# HTML5/CSS - When content is added to a SECTION the position moves. Why?

Tags: css, html

I'm having trouble understanding why the section within my layout is moving positions when content is added to it.
My intention is to have three sections per row horizontally aligned to each other.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/z6mx3/1/

css

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#container {
    background-color:Silver;
    width:1024px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px; 
    padding-bottom:20px;
    min-height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

#content {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#664E44;
    background-color:red;
    overflow:auto;
}


section {
    color:#24292E;
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 15px;
    background-color:#A8B1B1;
    padding:4px;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">                        
            <div id="content">
                <section>
                <h2>Header</h2>
                <p></p>
                </section>

                <section>

                </section>

                <section>
                </section>

                <section>
                </section>

                <section>
                </section>

                <section>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you add `float:left;` to `section` they are nice aligned to each other.. Is that what you were trying to do?

Comment: thanks, but the reason I chose to use inline-block is so I can horizontally center the sections within the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default alignment for `inline-block` items is `baseline`.

You just need to add the correct alignment option to your CSS

```
section {
    color:#24292E;
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 15px;
    background-color:#A8B1B1;
    padding:4px;
    vertical-align:top /* here*/ 
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/z6mx3/9/)